# Disable windows error box on specific apps

Tags: windows-10, popups, windows-error-reporting

How can I disable Windows Error box from popping up?

We have machines that get the pop up box saying something went wrong,

I don't want to turn off Windows Error Service tho, just want to disable Error pop up on specific apps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You may use a product such as AutoHotKey to wait for the error dialog and press the OK button. Let me know if this is a solution. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc this is what I'm looking into! Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to turn off Windows Error Service tho, just want to
> disable Error pop up on specific apps.

To the best of my knowledge and a lot of use, if the Error Service is ON and you get an error, you cannot disable the pop up and certainly not by App.

Best (1) to correct the error (after the work is over) to eliminate the pop up and (2) live with the pop up until corrected.

Comment: the problem is, this is a render farm and sometimes in the middle of a job they would run into issues caused by many different factors, So I can't eliminate the error from happening, but then the App would generate a generic pop up error, I want to disable that however I need windows error for troubleshooting other stuff.

Comment: I understand, but if services are running normally, the the Error will pop up.  Try troubleshooting a prior error to correct the problem

Comment: Or have the app **trap** the error, and log it, either to an internal log or to the Windows Error Log. Each language has a method to handle exceptions gracefully. For example, C#: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_exception_handling.htm, C+: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/errors-and-exception-handling-modern-cpp?view=msvc-170, Java: https://www.javatpoint.com/exception-handling-in-java ... You should use an app with better exception handling!

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you my friend, that's a good clue to start with.

Comment: @John Thanks for your answer, troubleshooting prior to the error is not possible.

Comment: But working from the log after the error should provide some clue as to the error.